# I didn't get any interface to setup Password and User name while installing mysql-server

Tags: mysql, database, operating-system

1. I useed the first command to install in Elementary OS

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```
2. Next i tried `mysql` and got such error, please help me out i am beginner in mysql and Linux

> sudhanshu@sudhanshu-Lenovo-G570:~/Downloads$ mysql
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sudhanshu'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Did you get asked for a password for the `root` user account as part of the install?

Comment: Unless you have created a user account called `'sudhanshu'@'localhost'` it wont exist by default

Comment: i have never installed any DB, few days before only i have installed a new OS. How can this be possible??